# Convert number to 3 digit number if required

Tags: c#, integer, string-conversion

Wondering if anybody has any pointers for this.

I currently need to convert an integer to a three digit number as a string.

My scenario is this:

- If number = 1 then it will be converted to 001
- If number = 10 then it will be converted to 010
- If number = 100 then it will remain 100

Thanks

Comment: What shall be the _type_? If it's an `int` and you want to keep it an `int`: you can't.

Comment: My apologies I should have stated - I would then convert it to a string